# Intellij Gradle project cannot resolve assertEquals with junit 4.11 as the testCompile dep

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to set up a simple gradle project in the latest version of Intellij IDEA (13.0.2).

I have no dependencies other than JUnit 4, my build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

I'm trying to use assertEquals in my Main class test suite, but Intellij is giving me the "Cannot resolve method assertEquals(int, int)" for the following two instances of it's use:

```
package ag.kge;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MainTest {

    Main testMain1;
    Main testMain2;


    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        testMain1 = new Main("9999");
        testMain2 = new Main("args");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPort() throws Exception {
        assertEquals (testMain1.getPort(), 9999);
        assertEquals (testMain2.getPort(), 5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartThreads() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Also, Intellij indicates tells me that the import org.junit.Assert.* isn't used.

If anyone knows why I'm having this problem, I'd really appreciate the help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
import org.junit.Assert.*;
```

should be

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and fixed it by changing assertEquals to

```
Assert.assertEquals
```

and

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using IntelliJ 2019.2.4 with a start.sping.io default setup...

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
```

but instead of

```
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

use

```
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just did intelliJ and had the same issues, my auto fix
[press option + enter button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cPav.png)

it imported this:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
```

then auto fixed this for my test

```
@Test
void UserService() {
//testing login
UserService service = new UserService();
UserServiceBean bean = new UserServiceBean();
bean.setEmail("bean@testing");
bean.setUsername("Frank");
UserServiceBean login = service.login(bean);
assertEquals(login.getEmail(), actual:"bean@testing");
```

IntelliJ has a neat auto-fix button that will help you format your code correctly. My code now runs correctly to Junit selected and is formatted correctly.

Be sure to highlight over the Assert.assertEquals(), before you opt to fix the format of your code, so IntelliJ will tell how to do that for you-

Comment: I used gradle, and springboot in intelliJ- with Java 8